# Need to connect to 'old' .mdb files, from 64-bit MS Access

Tags: vba

Is there a way to connect to an old .mdb file from 64-bit Access?

I've been trying to do this, off-and-on now, for a long time, and have yet to find a solution.  (I've tried manually connecting, and tried coding via VBA, using ADO, OLE, ODBC, whatever - nothing works.

I admit I'm a little annoyed at the mindset that assumes we are all "driving shiny new cars".  Some of us have to use old software - that's just the way it is.  And to have absolutely NO support for old versions is very frustrating.  How dare we drive a 10-year-old car!?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe the exact problem you're having?  64-bit vs 32-bit shouldn't be a problem, but are you talking about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-previous-version ?

Comment: I think that is a similar problem - although that one seems to be addressing issues within versions like 97 and 2000 etc.  I have .mdb files that I need access to that can *only* be accessed by the new 64-bit Access system, IF I first use my old Access 2010 to open and convert the .mdb file into the newer .accdb format.  I think Access 2010 was the last version to support converting.

Comment: Frustrating, sure, but Access 97 was 24 years ago now. MS is pretty good (fantastic in general, when you consider it) about backwards compatibility but maybe even they have a limit?

Comment: I guess so.  I do wonder how folks keep a 50s era car running...  ;-)  But in this case - I think the .mdb format I'm talking about was used up until 2010 - so the conversion routine needed isn't actually quite that old.  But granted - it is old indeed...  But again - not my fault... it's just the way it is. Oh well. I guess there is no way?